# When use datatables in Ajax call, paging is not working

Tags: ajax, datatables, paging

When I use the code below, paging is not working. Where am I wrong?

```
var data = '';
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "include/tables/data.php",   
     async: false,
     success: function(data) {  
           $("#result").html(data);
           $('#mytable').DataTable({});
     }
});
```

Comment: Use the built in [ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) option of datatables instead of JQuery ajax.

Comment: can you give me example please

Comment: There are a lot of good examples on the [datatables website](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/), depending on the format the data is returned from the server.